# Dimension of division ring over center cannot be prime

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Let $D$ be a division ring. Let $F$ be its center. Note that $F$ is a field, so $D$ is a vector space over $F$.

How do we show that $\dim_F D$ cannot be a prime?

---

What I tried is proving by contradiction. Suppose $\dim_F D=p$, then there exists a basis $\{x_1,\dots,x_p\}$ of $D$.

Then $1=a_1x_1+\dots+a_px_p$ for some $a_i\in F$.

Perhaps use the fact that characteristic of $F$ is either 1 or prime here? I am not sure how to continue.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: A non-trivial (but still basic) fact is that $\dim_FD$ is a square when finite. Your claim follows from that. Of course, rschwieb's nice solution gets away with less theory!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ah I see... forgot all about central simple algebras..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help. Hint:

Think along the lines of a field extension. $F=D$ there's nothing to prove. If $\alpha\in D\setminus F$, then $F[\alpha]\subseteq D$ is a field extension of $F$ with index $[F[\alpha]: F]>1$.

Now, $D$ is a vector space over this field as well. How do $[F[\alpha]: F]$, $[D:F[\alpha]]$ and $[D:F]$ relate?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see the tower law will be useful here. But what if $[D:F(\alpha)]=1$? Then $[D:F]=[F(\alpha):F]$ may still be prime.

Comment: @yoyostein: Surely $F[\alpha]$ is commutative. $F$ commutes with all of $D$, and $\alpha$ commutes with itself. Therefore ...